# No public key available for the following key IDs: AA8E81B4331F7F50

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker

Below command:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y && \
    easy_install pip
```

is giving error:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y &&     easy_install pip
 ---> Running in 25a6ae724b15
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [901 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 17s (573 kB/s)
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
AA8E81B4331F7F50
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y &&     easy_install pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

To try resolving this error, below are the changes done:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y && \
    easy_install pip
```

---

Problem still remains with below error:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 &&     apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y &&     easy_install pip
 ---> Running in d51497786a78
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.XQtj1WUFSF --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50
gpg: requesting key 331F7F50 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 8AE22BA9: public key "Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages

Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [901 kB]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 10.1 MB in 17s (587 kB/s)
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 &&     apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y &&     easy_install pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

1) What is the meaning of this error?

2) How to resolve this error?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515937/117549

Answer (score 8):

AA8E81B4331F7F50 is the Stretch (release after Jessie) signing key. You could fix that by installing a newer `debian-archive-keyring` package, but I doubt you actually need to.

However, your bigger issue is that you're using jessie-backports. That was EOL'd along with Jessie (backports does not get long-term support). If you want to use the old, unsupported jessie-backports packages, you need to grab them from `http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/` instead. Also, archived material is not re-signed, so the signature is expired. Per [Failed to Fetch Jessie Backports Repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508728/86440), the `sources.list` entry would look like:

```
deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Also, `httpredir.debian.org` is no more; you probably want `deb.debian.org` instead. See https://deb.debian.org/ for instructions.

*(What you really ought to do, of course, is build your container on the current release, Buster.)*

Comment: The configuration needed for Jessie is detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508728/86440), validity checks need to be disabled entirely. But really, container images based on Jessie should be avoided at this point.

Comment: Do I need to update sources.lst? Am not getting this answer

Comment: what is debian-archive-keyring?

Comment: @overexchange I've clarified some, does that help? You need to edit sources.list. And debian-archive-keyring is a package name.

Comment: Why is this question offtopic? askubuntu moderator suggested me to post here

Comment: @overexchange Normally only one copy of a question is supposed to be "open" on the Stack Exchange network. You ought to ping  JeffSchaller or one of the other mods if you want this one open instead of the [ubuntu.se] one.